# Writing asp.net code to run on client side

Tags: asp.net, javascript, client-side

Is there a way (except for using JS on the html view) to tell asp.net to run a certain code on client side (instead of server side)?

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is NO, the language of browser is JavaScript, at least you can use some activX controls, Silverlight , Flash, Applets or such a things

Answer (score 0):

Only with `<script>` tags, and the only well-supported language is javascript.

Answer (score 0):

No. The only thing you can run client side is JavaScript. If you do need more client-side functionality you could consider using Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/)

Script# allows you to create client side script in C# !!!! 
You write your C# code in Visual Studio and the 'compiled output' gets translated into plain JavaScript. 
The new MS Web Office makes use of Script# .